# How to reverse proxy to a Node.js app in a domain subfolder with Nginx on CentOS?

Tags: node.js, nginx, centos

I have a domain https://ytdownvideo.com running a WordPress website.

I want to run a Node.js app in a subfolder on the same domain, as follows: https://ytdownvideo.com/youtube/

I am using Nginx on CentOS 7 x64.

How can I configure Nginx to reverse proxy to the Node.js app when navigating to this subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to run your Node.js app on a different and unused port. For example, `3000`.

Then, add the following to your nginx configuration:

```
location ~ ^\/youtube.*$ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    port_in_redirect off;
}
```

Restart nginx with:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```